# Entity Framework Display SQL Used to Perform DB Request Anomaly

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Very strange situation. I am using EF 6.1 in a project along with my friend. He told that when he sets a breakpoint on return from this method

```
    private static List<Tag> PreloadTags(ref ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        var enumerableResult = db.Tags.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(PrefetchSize*TagsPerPicture);
        return enumerableResult.ToList();
    }
```

and howevers over the enumerableResult he sees the actual SQL query used to query the SQL server. However (and this is the anomaly), when I do this, I do not see the query. I only see the type System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery. I am using VS2013 Professional, he is using VS2013 Web Express. Any ideas? It is a great mystery to me although I am sure there is reasonable explanation.

Screenshot of him seeing the query.
[image: Screenshot of him seeing the query.]

Screenshot of me NOT seeing the query.
[image: Screenshot of me NOT seeing the query.]

Comment: Could you try a watch for `enumerableResult.ToString()`?

Comment: have you tried drilling into the object via the > ?

Comment: Chances are, it depends on some obscure setting deep within VS options. Try to import his VS settings onto your machine (backing up your current ones first, if necessary) and see whether it will help.